# There is no register form but spams are sending register request in Drupal 7!

Tags: advertising, users

There is no register or login form in `front-page` or any other pages in my website but every day I receive emails of my website that some people asked for registration, How does such a thing is possible and how do they do this?

Comment: Either there is register form somewhere, probably under http://example.com/user/register, or you are using core with a security bug.

Comment: the core has the latest update, I check them every day. How do I can disable `example.com/user/register` page?

Comment: What is the text of the email? Including headers

Comment: @AgA something like this: lionel33gmvblkfzjwfu has applied for an account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default there's a registration form at /user/register; bots will find it trivial to discover and submit that form.

If you really don't want that path to be accessible you can just use a menu alter to deny access:

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user/register']['access callback'] = FALSE;
}
```

Comment: return `$items`; is not needed?

Comment: `$items` is passed in by reference so no need to return

Answer (score 3):

Go to `admin/config/people/accounts` 
and configure : Registration and cancellation for administration only
[image]

Comment: I already did this before, but I was wondering how do they do this!]

Comment: @Drupalist Always put information in question what you tried.